# Build a bundle of packages using different folders during development

Tags: l3build

I'm developing small packages with a targeted use for each of them: for example, I'm finishing a tool around intervals, I'll do another one later to work with more general sets, etc.

I know that `l3build` makes it easy to put such packages online, but I'd like to know if I could indicate each package as part of a whole so as not to pollute the distributions' namespace like `TeXLive`.

Here's a fictitious example of a folder structure for development purposes.

```
+ mylatexdev
  + tnsinterval
    + tests-done-via-l3build
    + ...
  + tnslogic
    + tests-done-via-l3build
    + ...
  + tnsgeneset
    + tests-done-via-l3build
    + ...
```

Here's how I'd like users to see my projects on `CTAN` (the structure is simplified).

```
+ tns
  + tnsmath
    * tnsinterval.sty
    * tnslogic.sty
    * tnsgeneset.sty
```

Comment: ctan really prefer a flat structure, and doesn't require the `.sty` at all if they are generated from documented sources., The extracted files can be placed in a nested structure on texlive/miktex

Comment: I don't see how this would avoid 'polluting' any namespace. Whatever directory structure you use, each filename needs to be unique. You can't have two `tnsinterval.sty`, however many parent directories you insert.

Comment: @cfr I was thinking of using GUIs like the one of `TeXlive` on `MacO$`. Maybe I should put my final codes in a dedicated bundle folder where I let `l3build` do some testing and then publish to `CTAN`.

Comment: So the concern is the proliferation of directories? As @DavidCarlisle says, TL/MikTeX can use more structure, but CTAN now prefers flat. If the packages are uploaded as a single item, they'll generally end up under a common directory by default, as far as I know. How many packages are we talking about?

Comment: @cfr This can be up to twenty files. The package [oberdiek](https://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) gave me the idea to do this.

Comment: I don't see why that should be a problem, then. Just do flat for CTAN.